# How to delete old event on every click in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

My following code creates a new image on every left mouse click within a specific area of current window. How is it possible that i can create a new image on every click but also can delete the old one in result of the same click.

Here is my code.

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, title):
    super(MainWindow,self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(800,480))
    self.SetBackgroundColour('white')

    self.Show()
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.onLeftDown)


def onLeftDown(self, event):
    """left mouse button is pressed"""
    pt = event.GetX()
    if pt >= 100 and pt <= 700:
       png = wx.Image('input.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
       self.bitmap1 = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, png, (pt, 220), (5,60))

if __name__ == '__main__' :
  app = wx.App()
  MainWindow(None, title='App GUI')
  app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The png object is garbage collected at the end of the `onLeftDown()` method, I believe. Normally when you want to change a `StaticBitmap` widget's contents, you use its `SetBitmap` method. You might want to take a look at this tutorial for a good example of how to change which image you're viewing:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/26/creating-a-simple-photo-viewer-with-wxpython/